# Oracle error "no function exists in this scope", and I don't know how to correct it

Tags: sql, plsql

```
create or replace procedure TEST_P_EXEC_SQL(
p_prj IN varchar2,
p_sql IN CLOB,
fl_cosa IN varchar2,
p_out OUT CLOB
)
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
sql_str CLOB;
v_sseq varchar2(32);
v_err_cod NUMBER;
v_err_msg varchar2(512);
BEGIN
--dbms_output.enable;
select substr(to_char(dbms_random.value()),2,32) INTO v_sseq from dual;
insert into TEST_t_sql_log
select
P_PRJ,sysdate,NULL,P_SQL,0,NULL,v_sseq
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST') as DB_HOST
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'DB_NAME') as DB_NAME
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'INSTANCE') as DB_ISTANCE
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') as DB_SERVICE
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') as DB_USER
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SID') as DB_SID
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'HOST') as MACHINE
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') as OS_USER
,SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE') as PROGRAM
FROM DUAL;
commit;
BEGIN
if fl_cosa != 'INTO' then
execute immediate p_sql;
else
execute immediate p_sql into p_out;
end if;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
v_err_cod := SQLCODE;
v_err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 512);
update TEST_t_sql_log
set TS_END = sysdate, sql_rc = v_err_cod, sql_tx = v_err_msg
where sql_log_seq = v_sseq;
commit;
raise;
end;
--dbms_output.put_line(v_errm);
update TEST_t_sql_log
set TS_END = sysdate
where sql_log_seq = v_sseq;
commit;
END;


declare
v_output clob;
begin
dbms_output.enable;
v_output := TEST_P_EXEC_SQL('TEST','select dummy from dual','INTO', 'test_out');
dbms_output.put_line(v_output);
enter code here`end;
```

When I call the function it returns the error PLS-00222 no function exists in this scope. I'm doing an internship with a somewhat different technical background so I unfortunately don't have the knowledge to understand what's wrong with the script. Thanks to everybody who'll find time to answer my probably simple question

Comment: You have created a procedure and you are calling it as if it were a function. Maybe see https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefcallprocedure.html

Comment: You have a number of errors some of them are: you have an nested begin end block in your procedure begin end block, `raise;` keyword in `when other then` exception does nothing, u use alias for columns in your insert statement for no reason at all, `end;` keyword in your block where u call procedure must be in new row and u have a procedure not a function so this is wrong `v_output := TEST_P_EXEC_SQL`, u have an out parameter in your procedure but u gave it a string literal 'test_out', and what is this: `enter code here` `

Comment: Ok, so how do I need to define the out parameter when I call the procedure?